# Error "ORA-24247: network access denied by access control list (ACL)" while debugging with Oracle SQL Developer

Tags: oracle, debugging, oracle-sqldeveloper, acl, remote-debugging

I'm trying to debug a procedure using "Oracle SQL Developer" version 23.1.0.097 from a PC with Windows 11.
I have established a connection to a remote Oracle Database 18c XE Release 18.0.0.0.0 on linux, using a SSH Tunnel.
I can execute succesfully the procedure while no debugging.

But when I try to debug it, it fails with some messages:

```
Connecting to the database #####.
Executing PL/SQL: CALL DBMS_DEBUG_JDWP.CONNECT_TCP( '127.0.0.1', '11183' )
ORA-24247: network access denied by access control list (ACL)
ORA-06512: at "SYS.DBMS_DEBUG_JDWP", line 68
ORA-06512: at line 1
Process exited.
Disconnecting from the database ####.
```

I searched online for possible solutions, but could not fix it. I granted the following to my user:

```
BEGIN
  DBMS_NETWORK_ACL_ADMIN.append_host_ace(
    host        => '*',
    lower_port  => 5001,
    upper_port  => 65535,
    ace         => xs$ace_type(privilege_list => xs$name_list('JDWP'), 
                               principal_name => 'MY-USER', /* replace with my real user*/
                               principal_type => xs_acl.ptype_db));
END;
```

But now the debugger fails with yet another message:

```
Executing PL/SQL: CALL DBMS_DEBUG_JDWP.CONNECT_TCP( '127.0.0.1', '14573' )
ORA-30683: failure establishing connection to debugger
ORA-12541: TNS:no listener
ORA-06512: at "SYS.DBMS_DEBUG_JDWP", line 68
ORA-06512: at line 1
Process exited.
```

But it makes no sense because **I am connected** to the database and using a SSH tunnel...

Comment: I doubt your ssh tunnel is forwarding the request back to your machine

Comment: Can you elaborate? I have no idea why the error message is "no listener"

Comment: The answer is in the message. If you can connect to the db on windows it means port 1521 (or whichever port for ur instance) is open.  The debugger uses a different port and it is not open by the looks of the response.  If this is a test instance, turn off the firewall or open the port and give it a another go.

Comment: Why would I need a listener running on my local client machine, as there is no database running here?

Also, seems like the debugger user a different port each time it is executed? "CALL DBMS_DEBUG_JDWP.CONNECT_TCP( '127.0.0.1', '11183' )" and "CALL DBMS_DEBUG_JDWP.CONNECT_TCP( '127.0.0.1', '14573' )" this time.

Comment: because jdwp has the Database make a connection BACK to your machine...that's why you had to define an ACL - that allows the db to make a network connection OUT to your box...where you should have sqldev ready to accept the debug connection request.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Now finally I am able to remote debug. I post my answer in case it can be useful to others.

After some research and tests, I couldn't fix my problems with DBMS_DEBUG_JDWP.

BUT:
I managed to remote debug as a wished, by using the old, deprecated but trusty DBMS_DEBUG.

In Tools > "Preferences > Debuger > Database Debug Drotocol": choose radio button "Use DBMS_DEBUG" instead of the default "Use DBMS_DEBUG_JDWP".